# Método set não funciona para preencher array de objetos

Tags: java, array

Criei uma classe `Funcionário`, e na classe `Main` criei um array
de objetos desse tipo. Agora estou tentando setar o atributo "cargo" dos funcionários em um loop, mas dá `NullPointerException`...

"OBS: O PROBLEMA REFERIDO NESSA PERGUNTA É SOBRE A NECESSIDADE DE 
CRIAÇÃO DE OBJETOS PARA CADA ÍNDICE DE UM ARRAY DE OBJETOS."

O método Set na classe Funcionário é simples:

```
public void setCargo(String cargo) {
    this.cargo = cargo;
}
```

Este é o código na main:

```
Funcionario[] funcis = new Funcionario[5];
Scanner ler = new Scanner(System.in);
int x=0;        

System.out.println("Informe os cargos: ");

for(x=0; x<funcis.length; x++){
    funcis[x].setCargo("testa");        //AQUI DA EXCEPTION NULLPOINTER
}
```

Comment: Complementando: ao criar o array de Funcionários, eu já estou alocando um objeto Funcionário em cada posição desse array? Ou só reservei o espaço de memória?

Comment: Você criou um array, mas não criou Funcionários e não os inseriu no array, por isso que dá NullPointerException.

Comment: Teria que fazer algo do tipo:   funcis[x] = new Funcionário();    dentro de um For então?

Comment: Deu certo! Valeu!